# PHP implementation of SOAP ws-addressing and ws-security

Tags: php, soap, ws-security, ws-addressing

I tried to call in PHP a SOAP webservice implemented in .Net using severals "extensions" like ws-security and ws-addressing.
I used wsf/php (wso2), based on rampart and axis2, and I did not succed. We asked another dev team which had developped these SOAP servers (in .Net), and they had failed too.
WSO2 seems to be unachieved, bugged, and not maintened. The last problem is a buffer overflow with key greater than 1024 bytes, but there were a bunch of problems before.

Who have implemented servers or clients using ws-*? With which libs and difficulties?

Comment: same as you. I couldn't even compile wso. It didn't work for you? Maybe I should stop and try to find an other solution. Did you succeed?

Comment: WSO 2.0.0 could only can be build with PHP 5.2. I was able to build WSO 2.1.0 with PHP 5.3, but it cannot manage 2048 bytes certificates. So I ask another compagnie to build a java client I call from the PHP application.